# "ReorderListBoxItem must have a DragHandle ContentPresenter part." issue

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-8

We are working on Windows Phone 8 app and try to use the [reorder list box control](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jasongin/archive/2011/01/03/wp7-reorderlistbox-improvements-rearrange-animations-and-more.aspx). For previous version of our app it's working. But now, when i bind the collection to the reorder list box, i've got exception `"System.InvalidOperationException"`

In details, i see this message.

> > System.InvalidOperationException: ReorderListBoxItem must have a DragHandleContentPresenter part.
> >         at ReorderListBoxDemo.ReorderListBoxItem.OnApplyTemplate()}

If anybody see such problem or know anything about it - please help. We use the MVVM light and bind data through ViewModel. But raw binding is not working at all. Sorry for my Russian English. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The control requires a Setter with Property="DragHandleTemplate". So simply copy the base [ItemContainerStyle from the Codeplex page of the control](http://reorderlistbox.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#main/Demo/MainPage.xaml) and extend it as required:

```
<rlb:ReorderListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style
        TargetType="rlb:ReorderListBoxItem">
        <Setter
            Property="DragHandleTemplate">
            <Setter.Value>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Canvas
                        Width="52"
                        Height="48"
                        Background="Transparent">
                        <Polygon
                            Fill="Gray"
                            Points="16,20 4,20 22,4 22,44 16,44" />
                        <Polygon
                            Fill="Gray"
                            Points="32,28 44,28 26,44 26,4 32,4" />
                    </Canvas>
                </DataTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</rlb:ReorderListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
```